# Rails routing model method parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the route

```
map.member 'members/:id/:name_url', :controller => 'members', :action => 'show', :requirements => { :id => /\d+/ }
```

and on my Member model I have a name_url method which takes the name and converts it to lowercase and changes spaces to dashes

the problem is that if I run

```
link_to "Bill", member
```

it gives me an "member_url failed to generate from" error

is there a way to achieve that? I was thinking a view helper that generated the link, but I couldn't access that from the controller if I needed to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the show action of the `MembersController`

```
class MembersController

  def show
    @member = Member.find_by_name("Bill")
  end
```

In `app/views/members/show.html.erb`, You'll want to use:

```
<%= link_to @member.name, member_path(@member, :name_url => "something") %>
```

Comment: yes, that will work too, I was more curious if there was still a way to keep the short syntax of: link_to 'Bill', member

Comment: If brevity is the concern, maybe creating a helper function is the way to go?

in the view:

<%= member_link @member %>

in the helper file:

def member_link(member)
  link_to member.name, member_path(member, :name_url => member.name_url)
end

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the :name_url parameter in your route:

```
map.member 'members/:id/:name_url', :controller => 'members', :action => 'show', :requirements => { :id => /\d+/ }
```

When you pass an ActiveRecord object as an option for url_for (which is what link_to does), Rails will implicitly call the model's to_param method. Which unless overridden only returns id the id. You could override to_param, but that won't give you the url you want. Because to_param is used to create the string that replaces id in urls. The best you could do with minimum changes is settle for something like this:

```
members/:id
```

where :id is actually `:id-:name_url`

Really the best option is what Dan McNevin suggests. However if that's too long for you, you can always just make it a helper:

```
def link_to_member member
  link_to member.name, member_url(member, :name_url => member.name)
end
```

And use it in place of link_to.

`link_to "Bill", member` => `link_to_member member`

Comment: I will add it to the application helper then, the only trouble is that I can't access that helper from the controller... or can I?

Comment: You can include the helpers in the controllers you need them. However, you shouldn't be using link_to in a controller.

Comment: I won't, I was just trying to get the path